# How do I prevent firefox from automatically redirecting to https

Tags: firefox, https

I use apache on my localhost for hosting sites that I'm working on.
I've started using firefox.

When I'm working locally on a website I don't set up SSL.

When I try to load my local site in firefox, firefox attempts to load the site with a 'https' prefix. This happens if I omit the protocal part of the URI, or if I explicitly type in 'http'.

Of course my site doesn't load. SSL is not enabled on the site.

How can I stop firefox from trying to redirect?

btw - the site itself consists of a single text file with the word 'hello' in that file.
There is no js or serverside logic implementing the redirect.

Comment: Have you tried https://itadminguide.com/disable-https-redirect-in-firefox/?